# Invalid operands to binary expressions?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to compare the letters two strings using the code provided below but keep getting this error.

THIS CODE IS THE CODE IM TRYING

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<int> solve(std::vector<std::string> arr){  

  std::string underCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  std::string upperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  int counter = 0;

  for(int i=0; i < arr.size(); i++){

    (underCase[i] == arr[i]) ? counter++ : 0;

    (upperCase[i] == arr[i]) ? counter++ : 0;

  }

  return counter;//your code herw

};
```

This is the error output that I get but I don't seem to understand it.

```
main.cpp:13:19: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'value_type' (aka 'std::__1::basic_string<char>'))
    (underCase[i] == arr[i]) ? counter++ : 0;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:19: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'value_type' (aka 'std::__1::basic_string<char>'))
    (upperCase[i] == arr[i]) ? counter++ : 0;
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~
main.cpp:16:10: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'int' to function return type 'std::vector<int>'
  return counter;//your code herw
         ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: OK, next step is to post a [mcve].

Comment: `counter` is an `int` and not a `std::vector<int>`. That's what the error message says. Voted to close that question as useless. There's no value for any future research.

Comment: All types returned by a ternary "?:" Must be the *same* type.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I see thank you! I was not aware of that condition.

Comment: Stop abusing ternary conditional operators in order to write unreadable code. What's wrong with an if statement? You can write it in one line if you want, although that's generally not recommended. If you think it's faster or something, it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
underCase[i] == arr[i]
```

You are trying to compare a `char` (the elements of `std::string`) with an entire `std::string` (the elements of `std::vector<std::string>`).

It seems you may want:

```
underCase[i] == upperCase[i]
```

or something like:

```
underCase[?] == arr[i][?]
```

Further, it is a good idea to use proper `if`s rather than the conditional operator:

```
if (upperCase[i] == upperCase[i])
    counter++;
```

Comment: I do apologize that I left the general problem very ambiguous, thank you for helping me! The idea was that a string was passed and if the letter of a string "arr" matched with a the letter's position in the alphabet then the counter would increase by 1.

Comment: @EyyLmao I would suggest you add that explanation in the question, and wait for new answers :)

Comment: Thank you, I really didn't think it through it was my first time using this forum but I understand thank you for taking the time to help me!

Comment: i understand exactly what you're saying now thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your return type does not match the return type of your function. int and vector
2. You didn't template the type of vector in your formal parameters.

Fixing those 2 things allows it to run on my machine. Whatever the purpose is.